# How do I eliminate the other wrong answers?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{u_n\}$ be a sequence of real  umbers satisfying the following conditions:

(1)$(-1)^nu_n\ge 0$

(2)$|u_{n+1}|<\frac{|u_n|}{2}$, for all $n\ge 13$.

Which of the following statements necessarily true?

(A)$\sum_{n\ge 1}u_n$ doesnot converges in $\mathbb R$.

(B)$\sum_{n\ge 13}u_n$ converges to zero.

(C)$\sum_{n\ge 13}u_n$ converges to a non-zero real number.

(D)If $|u_{n-1}|<\frac{|u_{n}|}{2},$ for all $2\leq n \leq 13,$ Then $\sum_{n\geq 1}u_n$ is a negative real number.

My attempt:

By Leibniz test for alternative series, The $\sum_{n\ge 13}u_n$ converges to a real number. So, (A) is false. Please help me to eliminate the other options?

Comment: $(B)$ is also false. Take $u_n = (-1)^n \frac {1} {n!},\ n\geq 1.$

Comment: @Dbchatto67 But in the answer key they gave (D) to be true.

Comment: @Unknownx I agree, (D) is true.

Comment: Yeah! I have done a mistake. Sorry.

Comment: Observe that $|u_{13+n} | < \frac {|u_{13}|} {2^n},$ for all $n \geq 13.$ So $$0 \leq \left |\sum\limits_{n \geq 13} u_n \right | \leq \sum\limits_{n \geq 1}\frac {|u_{13}|} {2^n} = u_{13}.$$ Choose $u_{13} =0.$ Then you will end up with $$\sum\limits_{n \geq 13} u_n = 0,$$ which violates $(C).$

Comment: @InterstellarProbe check my above comment.

Comment: @Dbchatto67 If $u_{13}=0$, then you need $|u_{14}|< \dfrac{|u_{13}|}{2} = 0$. Since $|u_{14}|$ is nonnegative, this is impossible.

Comment: I believe (C) is correct, as well.

Comment: Yeah! I have understood that already. But at least we can say that $$0 \leq \left |\sum\limits_{n \geq 13} u_n \right | \leq |u_{13}|$$ if the given condition holds.

Comment: @Unknownx I believe you can show that $$u_{13} < \sum_{n\ge 13} u_n < u_{13}+u_{14} < \dfrac{u_{13}}{2}$$ fairly easily to show that (C) is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $u_{13} < 0.$ Now the given condition implies that $$\sum\limits_{n \geq 13} u_n \leq u_{13} \sum\limits_{n \geq 0} \frac {(-1)^n} {2^n}  = u_{13} \left (1 + \frac 1 2 \right )^{-1} = \frac {2} {3} u_{13} < 0.$$ So $(C)$ is definitely true. Hence $(B)$ is always false.

Moreover if $|u_{n-1}| < \frac {|u_n|} {2},$ for all $2 \leq n \leq 13$ then we have $$\begin{align*} \sum\limits_{n \geq 1} u_n & = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{12} u_n + \sum\limits_{n \geq 13} u_n. \\ & < u_{13} \cdot \left ( \sum\limits_{n=1}^{12} \frac {(-1)^n} {2^n} \right ) + \frac {2} {3} u_{13}. \\ & = \left ( \frac 2 3 - \frac {4095} {3 \cdot 2^{12}} \right ) u_{13}. \\ & = \frac {4097} {3 \cdot 2^{12}} u_{13} < 0. \end{align*}$$

So $(D)$ is also true.

Comment: You pretend that $u_{15}<(-1)^2\frac{u_{13}}{2^2}$, but it is not the condition. Instead, it is given that the magnitude of $u_{15}$ is less than $1/4$ th of magnitude of $u_{13}$, right? This exactly says that $u_{15}>\frac{u_{13}}{2^2}$.